# Find and Run an SQL Script from Command Line

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, find

i am learning to use terminal with linux.
I am trying to find and run an SQL script from command line.

So far i manage to run an SQL script from terminal with:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname < script.sql
```

and also find the file that i want with:

```
find /path/to/migrations/directory | sort -r | head -1
```

(This `find` command finds the most recent sql script in the path)

But i could not figure out how to combine them like:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname < find /path/to/migrations/directory | sort -r | head -1
```

Basically, what i am trying to do is execute the result of `find` as sql script.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

In order to expand the file command you will need to use $() and so the command will be:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname < "$(find /path/to/migrations/directory | sort -r | head -1)"
```

Use quotes to deal with any issues associated with spaces in the expansion.

Comment: thakns for your help

Comment: No worries. If the answer was useful. Please like and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To take literally what you asked here, it would be

```
find /path/to/migrations/directory | sort -r | head -1 | mysql -u username -p dbname
```

However, your approach breaks if the SQL script you are looking for, is either NOT the first file (in the current collating sequence of your shell) in or below your directory, or if there are subdirectories of `directory`which come in sorting order BEFORE your desired script.

If there are several files below `directory`, but only one is an sql file, you can write it as

```
find /path/to/migrations/directory -type f -name '*.sql' -exec mysql -u username -p dbname {} \;
```

The `type f` ensures that `find` does not produce directory names, and the `-name` clause restricts the selection to names ending in *.sql*

But still then, I would add  some safety measurements to avoid picking up an unappropriate SQL script. For instance you could first collect all the SQL files below `directory`, and if the total number is greater than 1, not run it, but issue a message on stderr instead, saying "can not find sql file unambiguously".

Comment: thakns, my directory only contains sql scripts and i ment to choose the most recent file, appreciated your help :)

Comment: Be careful, by suggestion - as your code - does not locate the most recent file, but the first one in whatever order `find` locates. Then, if you don't have nested directories, I wonder why you are using `find` at all ..... Maybe you would get better answers if you not only post your current solution (which of course was good to do), but also define exactly what you want to achieve. You have never mentione the "most recent" criterion before; if this is important, it invalidates all answers, and I suggest that you ask a new, more precise question for your problem.